# Linux DMA API questions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, dma

Following the text at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API.txt a few inlined questions

```
Part Ia - Using large dma-coherent buffers
------------------------------------------

void *
dma_alloc_coherent(struct device *dev, size_t size,
                 dma_addr_t *dma_handle, gfp_t flag)

Consistent memory is memory for which a write by either the device or
the processor can immediately be read by the processor or device
without having to worry about caching effects.  (You may however need
to make sure to flush the processor's write buffers before telling
devices to read that memory.)
```

Q1. Is it safe to assume that the area allocated is cacheable ? As the last line state that flushing is required

Q1a. Does this API allocate memory from lower 16MB which is considered DMA safe.

```
dma_addr_t
dma_map_single(struct device *dev, void *cpu_addr, size_t size,
              enum dma_data_direction direction)

Maps a piece of processor virtual memory so it can be accessed by the
device and returns the physical handle of the memory.

The direction for both api's may be converted freely by casting.
However the dma_ API uses a strongly typed enumerator for its
direction:

DMA_NONE        no direction (used for debugging)
DMA_TO_DEVICE       data is going from the memory to the device
DMA_FROM_DEVICE     data is coming from the device to the memory
DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL   direction isn't known
```

Q2. Does the DMA_XXX options direct change of Page Attributes for the VA=>PA mapping. Say DMA_TO_DEVICE would mark the area as non-cacheable ?

Answer (score 7):

It says "without having to worry about caching effects". That means `dma_alloc_coherent()` returns uncacheable memory unless the architecture has cache coherent DMA hardware so the caching makes no difference. However being uncached does not mean that writes do not go through the CPU write buffers (i.e. not every memory access is immediately executed or executed in the same order as they appear in the code). To be sure that everything you write into memory is really there when you tell the device to read it, you will have to execute a `wmb()` at least. See Documentation/memory-barriers.txt for more information.

`dma_alloc_coherent()` does not return memory from the lower 16 MB, it returns memory that is accessible by the device inside the addressable area specified by `dma_set_coherent_mask()`. You have to call that as part of the device initialization.

Cacheability is irrelevant to `dma_map_*()` functions. They make sure that the given memory region is accessible to the device at the DMA address they return. After the DMA is finished `dma_unmap_*()` is called. For DMA_TO_DEVICE the sequence is "write data to memory, map(), start DMA, unmap() when finished", for DMA_FROM_DEVICE "map(), start DMA, unmap() when finished, read data from memory".

Cache makes no difference because usually you are not writing or reading the buffer while it is mapped. If you really have to do that you have to explicitly `dma_sync_*()` the memory before reading or after writing the buffer.

Comment: Coherent memory is cacheable on architectures (like x86) that have DMA-coherent caches.

Comment: @CL. Thanks, I incorporated that into my first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, but I have a some points (A) The line is still confusing - (You may however need
to make sure to flush the processor's write buffers before telling
devices to read that memory.) - It the memory is not cacheable why this line is required. wmb is not for explicit flushing, it is for completion of write (B) I understand your point on DMA_XXX but can you please elaborate its effect on attributes of a VA->PA mapping. What you are writing is a flow but i need to understand how it changes anything in MMU / Core

Comment: @mSO Given how slow main RAM is, CPUs may implement write buffers to make writing more efficient. This is independent of caching (or may also be used by the caches). You need the `wmb()` to make sure all the writes to memory completed before the write to the device telling it to start DMA. "Flushing" may be the wrong word, the CPU may implement this as a serialization point in the buffer that prevents reordering.

Comment: @mSO If you want to know how DMA mapping is implemented you will just have to look at the source code. A TO_DEVICE may just do the same as for the coherent case if the hardware supports it (a `wmb()` basically) or it may need to copy the whole buffer to a place that is actually accessible to DMA. Everything in there is architecture specific.

Comment: I am thinking on these lines (a)SoC DMA driver is unaware of map single or coherent, it has been given a src/dest address (b) When DMA completes the data is transferred to / from memory. (c) How does DMA_XXX come into picture (d) if using bounce buffers for >32 bit addresses the code would still be in DMA driver and not in linux DMA  layer. So my point is what DMA_XXX and dma_map_single are doing differently

Comment: Looking at sources other than MIPS there is nothing special on DMA_XXX    http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/mips/include/asm/io.h#L593 http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arc/include/asm/dma-mapping.h#L62